# Could not able to view data while toggle the button in react. No error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Not able to load person component while toggle button is clicked. no errors was found in console.

what is the  mistake with the below code?

On load no need to display person component. once toggle button is clicked i need to show person component with the dynamic content which is present in the state object persons array.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Person from "./Person";
class App extends Component {
 state = {
   showPerson: false,
    persons: [
    { id: 1, name: "this is person1", age: 21 },
    { id: 2, name: "this is person2", age: 22 },
    { id: 3, name: "this is person3", age: 23 }
   ]
 };

 togglePersons = () => {
   const doesShow = this.state.showPerson;
   this.setState({ showPerson: !doesShow });
  };

 render() {
  let persons = null;

   if (this.state.showPerson) {
    persons = (
     <div>
      {this.state.persons.map((person, index) => {
        <Person key={person.id} name={person.name} age={person.age} />;
      })}
     </div>
    );
   }

   return (
     <div>
       <h3>This is working</h3>
       <button type="button" onClick={this.togglePersons}>
       Toggle Persons
       </button>
      {persons}
   </div>
   );
  }
 }

export default App;
```

Person component is just displaying data which present in the props object

Answer (score 1):

Working example :

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
        showPerson: false,
        persons: [
            { id: 1, name: "this is person1", age: 21 },
            { id: 2, name: "this is person2", age: 22 },
            { id: 3, name: "this is person3", age: 23 }
        ]
    };

    togglePersons = () => {
        const doesShow = this.state.showPerson;
        this.setState({ showPerson: !doesShow });
    };

    render() {
        const { showPerson, persons } = this.state //Deconstructing your state to improve readability

        return (
            <div>
                <h3>This is working</h3>
                <button type="button" onClick={this.togglePersons}>
                    Toggle Persons
                </button>
                {showPerson && persons.map(({ id, name, age}) => <p key={id}> {name} : {age} </p>)}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'>
```

The error comes from your rendering condition, you forgot to return something in your `map`.

By using the inline if : `&&`, you can render your component depending on a condition.

Putting `{showPerson &&` in your JSX will only render the following code if `showPerson` exists.

You now only need to replace the `p` tag by your component.

I would also recommend using the callback version of `setState` when using your previous state to avoid any unexpected behavior :

```
togglePersons = () => {
    this.setState(prev => ({ showPerson: !prev.showPerson }))
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that you are not returning Person component inside map so you need to add return before Person component

But I would recommend you to keep render as much as clean. Whatever you do inside render can be directly implemented in return like below

Try with below render code

```
     render() {
       return (
           <div>
              <h3>This is working</h3>
             <button type="button" onClick={this.togglePersons}>
              Toggle Persons
              </button>
             {this.state.showPerson && this.state.persons.map((person, index) => (
                 <Person key={person.id} name={person.name} age={person.age} />;
             ))}
            );
           }
```

Comment: Please do accept and upvote if it resolves your issue

Answer (score 0):

Ok the *actual* problem here is you're not *returning* the `<Person>` component from your `map()` call:

```
 {this.state.persons.map((person, index) => {
     <Person key={person.id} name={person.name} age={person.age} />;
 })}
```

needs to be either

```
 {this.state.persons.map((person, index) => {
     return <Person key={person.id} name={person.name} age={person.age} />; // <- add "return"
 })}
```

or

```
 {this.state.persons.map((person, index) => ( // <- parentheses
     <Person key={person.id} name={person.name} age={person.age} /> // <- no semicolon or "return"
 ))}
```

In a lambda when you use a `{}` for the function body, you need to explicitly `return` the value.